# add or create new attributes using NCO

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have one .nc file in which I want to create a new attribute

like

```
float Longitude_Aerosol_NearUV_Swath(nTimes_Aerosol_NearUV_Swath, nXtrack_Aerosol_NearUV_Swath) ;
    Longitude_Aerosol_NearUV_Swath:standard_name = "longitude" ;
    Longitude_Aerosol_NearUV_Swath:long_name = "longitude" ;
    Longitude_Aerosol_NearUV_Swath:units = "degrees_east" ;
    Longitude_Aerosol_NearUV_Swath:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
```

please let me know how to add this in the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Read the fine manual [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncatted)

```
ncatted -a attribute_name,variable_name,o,c,'text string' in.nc out.nc
```